# How to edit column name in Visual Studio's SQL Compact?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I use WPF C# Visual Studio and SQL Compact 3.5. On server explorer, I right click and select "Edit Table Schema", I can only change the data type, length,..etc but I cannot click into the Column Name to change the column name. How to change the column name in Server Explorer?

[image]

Comment: How about doing the alternative in SQL Server Management Studio Express? As far as I know, Server Explorer in Visual Studio lets you modify the column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible in SQL server CE. You will have to create a new column and then remove the old one. If you have any data in your column you will need to migrate this to your new column first. If you want to do it with an sql statement, try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD newColumn newType

UPDATE myTable SET newColumn = oldColumn

ALTER TABLE myTable DROP COLUMN oldColumn
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sp_rename - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2007/08/hidden-gem-rename-table.html

Comment: If I may quote from your own blog: "Currently, sp_rename support in SQL Server Compact 3.5 is limited to tables. "

Comment: Of course, you are right, DataPort Console from Primeworks allows you to rename columns, only tool i know of